# Reformatting data- Giving each value in a list it's own row while retaining the list's ID

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I am looking to reformat some data. It currently looks like this:

[image: Site_ID Section_ID 1, "A100/2020, B100/1001, C130/2000" 2, "A100/2021, ZW00/2002, W300/0999" 3, "A100/2022, TS100/4000, RW100/0000"]

Using this as an example, the below is the format i'm trying to achieve:
[image]

So each element in the list gets it's own row, but the original site_ID is retained.
A solution in Python would be ideal as this is the only language I am currently comfortable with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use split with iterrows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{'Site_ID': 1, 'Section_ID': 'a,b,c'},
               {'Site_ID': 2, 'Section_ID': 'd,e,f'}])

df

  Site_ID   Section_ID  
0   1   a,b,c  
1   2   d,e,f  

pd.concat([pd.Series( row['Site_ID'], row['Section_ID'].split(',') ) for _, row in df.iterrows()])

a    1  
b    1  
c    1  
d    2  
e    2  
f    2
```

iterrows goes through the series row by row and split will find the separate values in a string that is separated by a comma.

If you want the column names back, you can convert back to a dataframe:

```
import numpy as np  
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(pd.concat([pd.Series( row['Site_ID'], row['Section_ID'].split(',') ) for _, row in df.iterrows()]).reset_index()), columns=['Site_ID','Section_ID'])  

df1

 Site_ID Section_ID
0   a   1
1   b   1
2   c   1
3   d   2
4   e   2
5   f   2
```